SetCurve doesn’t work at runtime in Unity build with Animancer (non-humanoid avatar)
I'm trying to generate and play animations at runtime in Unity using Animancer. My current implementation uses AnimationClip.SetCurve to create and play the animation, which works perfectly in the Editor but fails in a runtime build because SetCurve is an Editor-only function.
Here's my current code:
public AnimationClip CreateAnimationClipFromBCK(BMD bmd, BCK bck, string startBone = "##STOP##")
{
    AnimationClip clip = new AnimationClip();
    clip.name = bck.Name.Replace(".bck", "");

    if (bck.LoopMode == LoopType.Loop) clip.wrapMode = UnityEngine.WrapMode.Loop; 
    if (bck.LoopMode == LoopType.Once) clip.wrapMode = UnityEngine.WrapMode.Once;

    List<SkeletonJoint> pose = bmd.JNT1Tag.AnimatedJoints;
    if (bck.m_animationData == null) return null;

    int numJoints = Math.Min(pose.Count, bck.m_animationData.Count);
    AnimationCurveHolder animationData = new AnimationCurveHolder();

    for (int i = 0; i < numJoints; i++)
    {
        string boneName = pose[i].Name;
        if(startBone != "##STOP##") if (!IsDescendantOf(pose[i], startBone)) continue;

        var jointAnim = bck.m_animationData[i];
        string path = GetFullPath(pose[i]);

        animationData.PositionCurvesX[path] = new AnimationCurve();
        animationData.PositionCurvesY[path] = new AnimationCurve();
        animationData.PositionCurvesZ[path] = new AnimationCurve();
        animationData.RotationCurvesX[path] = new AnimationCurve();
        animationData.RotationCurvesY[path] = new AnimationCurve();
        animationData.RotationCurvesZ[path] = new AnimationCurve();
        animationData.RotationCurvesW[path] = new AnimationCurve();
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < bck.AnimLengthInFrames; j++)
    {
        float ftime = j;
        for (int i = 0; i < numJoints; i++)
        {
            if(startBone != "##STOP##") if (!IsDescendantOf(pose[i], startBone)) continue;

            var jointAnim = bck.m_animationData[i];
            string path = GetFullPath(pose[i]);

            OpenTK.Vector3 translation = new OpenTK.Vector3(
                bck.GetAnimValue(jointAnim.TranslationsX, ftime),
                bck.GetAnimValue(jointAnim.TranslationsY, ftime),
                bck.GetAnimValue(jointAnim.TranslationsZ, ftime)
            );

            OpenTK.Vector3 rot = new OpenTK.Vector3(
                bck.GetAnimValue(jointAnim.RotationsX, ftime),
                bck.GetAnimValue(jointAnim.RotationsY, ftime),
                bck.GetAnimValue(jointAnim.RotationsZ, ftime)
            );

            pose[i].Rotation =
                OpenTK.Quaternion.FromAxisAngle(new OpenTK.Vector3(0, 0, 1), WMath.DegreesToRadians(rot.Z)) *
                OpenTK.Quaternion.FromAxisAngle(new OpenTK.Vector3(0, 1, 0), WMath.DegreesToRadians(rot.Y)) *
                OpenTK.Quaternion.FromAxisAngle(new OpenTK.Vector3(1, 0, 0), WMath.DegreesToRadians(rot.X));

            animationData.PositionCurvesX[path].AddKey(ftime, translation.X);
            animationData.PositionCurvesY[path].AddKey(ftime, translation.Y);
            animationData.PositionCurvesZ[path].AddKey(ftime, translation.Z);
            animationData.RotationCurvesX[path].AddKey(ftime, pose[i].Rotation.X);
            animationData.RotationCurvesY[path].AddKey(ftime, pose[i].Rotation.Y);
            animationData.RotationCurvesZ[path].AddKey(ftime, pose[i].Rotation.Z);
            animationData.RotationCurvesW[path].AddKey(ftime, pose[i].Rotation.W);
        }
    }

    foreach (var kvp in animationData.PositionCurvesX) clip.SetCurve(kvp.Key, typeof(Transform), "localPosition.x", kvp.Value);
    foreach (var kvp in animationData.PositionCurvesY) clip.SetCurve(kvp.Key, typeof(Transform), "localPosition.y", kvp.Value);
    foreach (var kvp in animationData.PositionCurvesZ) clip.SetCurve(kvp.Key, typeof(Transform), "localPosition.z", kvp.Value);
    foreach (var kvp in animationData.RotationCurvesX) clip.SetCurve(kvp.Key, typeof(Transform), "localRotation.x", kvp.Value);
    foreach (var kvp in animationData.RotationCurvesY) clip.SetCurve(kvp.Key, typeof(Transform), "localRotation.y", kvp.Value);
    foreach (var kvp in animationData.RotationCurvesZ) clip.SetCurve(kvp.Key, typeof(Transform), "localRotation.z", kvp.Value);
    foreach (var kvp in animationData.RotationCurvesW) clip.SetCurve(kvp.Key, typeof(Transform), "localRotation.w", kvp.Value);

    _animationCurveHolders.Add(animationData);
    return clip;
}

Basically what my code does is reading the keyframes from a binary animation file (BCK - file format for GameCube) and adds them to the AnimationClip via SetCurve.
Since SetCurve is an Editor-only function, this approach only works in the Editor. I've come across a similar issue in this GitHub issue where SetCurve limitations were discussed, but I’m unsure how to adapt the solution because I’m not using a humanoid avatar.
That's the link: https://github.com/KybernetikGames/animancer/issues/362
Does anyone know of an alternative approach to create animation clips at runtime without SetCurve? Any insights would be appreciated, especially if you’ve worked with non-humanoid avatars and runtime animation generation and playing them with Animancer Pro.

SetCurve works for the legacy clips to be used in the Animation component .. if you ca use that instead then yes you can create animations on runtime ... afaik there is no way to do this for the Animator ...

Yeah, I know that. But it should be possible to create custom states for Animancer (this state is not a regular AnimationClip tho). See the GitHub link
